# Set body of Outlook email from a Word file preserving the format (text location, images)

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

My goal is create an outlook message that its body is generated from a word document that the client can modify.

I've tried saving the word document in different file formats (.html, .mht), but in all of these, the image I had in the word document didn't appear in the body of Outlook.

[Image - Example of the problem](http://postimg.org/image/7t76c8ktn/)

Comment: If you solved you issue please provide solution. I have same issue.